# Send data from js prompt to expressjs route

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am trying to get the value of my prompt in order to update a category via the javascript function prompt however I just don't know how to do it as I'm used to having a form in order to pass on variables to the request.body.

My code looks like this
The javascript for the prompt

```js
    <div style="margin-bottom: 2%; margin-top: 2%;">
        <% categorys.forEach(function(category){ %>
            <h2 style="display: inline;"><%= category.category_name %></h2>
            <a onclick="updateCategory()" class="update-category" href="/api/category/update/<%= category.category_id %>">Update</a>
            <a href="/api/category/delete/<%= category.category_id %>">Delete</a>
            <br>
        <% }); %>
    </div>

    <script>
        function updateCategory() {
            var category_name = prompt("Please enter category_name")
            var clickedOk = confirm("Are you sure you want to update?");
            $("#category_name").val() = category_name;
        }

    </script>
```

And my route

```js
router.get('/update/:id', async(req, res) => {
    // Checks if we are authenticated, if not then raise 401 unauthorized status code.
    sess = req.session;
    if(!sess.authenticated) return res.status(401).send("Unauthorized please login.");
    console.log(req.body)
    if(!req.body) return res.send('empty body');

    const respUpdateCategory = await ourCategory.updateCategory(req.params.id, req.body.category_name)
    if(respDeleteCategory) {
        return res.status(201).send('Succesful!')
    } else {
        return res.statusCode(400).send('Something broke!')
    }
});
```

Comment: ```$("#category_name").val() = category_name;``` what are you want to do here?? in ```category_name``` variable you get your desire value of prompt...

Comment: I want to send it to the route where it gets req.body.category_name

Comment: Then, get the value, use Ajax to send the data to server

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it since I had some problems on the backend which I fixed before trying however making a hidden input with the name and id of category_name and then setting the value of that within the javascript after it has been confirmed.